# Cumulative sum of unique elements sorted by other element in a nested array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, unique

I have the following MySQL query (`timestamp` is in Unix time, obviously):

```sql
SELECT usr_id, CONCAT(YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)), "/", MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)), "/", DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp))) as date_stamp
FROM table
ORDER BY YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)), MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)), DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp));
```

This produces something like this:

```php
$arr = array(
    array('usr_id'=>3, 'date_stamp'=>'2011/6/6'),
    array('usr_id'=>2, 'date_stamp'=>'2011/6/20'),
    array('usr_id'=>2, 'date_stamp'=>'2011/6/20'), // same id and date as above
    array('usr_id'=>5, 'date_stamp'=>'2011/6/20'), // same date as above
    array('usr_id'=>1, 'date_stamp'=>'2011/6/21'),
    array('usr_id'=>4, 'date_stamp'=>'2011/6/21'), // same date as above
    array('usr_id'=>2, 'date_stamp'=>'2011/6/21'), // same date as above...
        //... and same id as a day before
);
```

I would like to turn it into something like this:

```php
$arr = array(
    array('sum'=>1, 'date_stamp'=>'2011/6/6'),
    array('sum'=>3, 'date_stamp'=>'2011/6/20'), // +2 as one of the 3...
        //... for this date was a duplicate
    array('sum'=>5, 'date_stamp'=>'2011/6/21'), // +2 as one of the 3...
        //... was already there on a different day
);
```

This is what I've tried, but I only later realised that it's only taking care of uniqueness for a given date, not the entire array as I intend it to do:

```php
$sum = 0;
$tempRes = array();
$result = array(); 
$date = null;
foreach($arr as $row)
{
    $date = $row['date_stamp'];
    if (!in_array($row['usr_id'], $tempRes))
        $tempRes[$date][] = $row2['usr_id'];
}
foreach ($tempRes as $date2 => $ids)
{
    $sum += count($ids);
    $result[] = array($date2, $sum);
}
```

Basically the purpose is to produce the cumulative sum of the number of `usr_id`'s per day and ensure the same `usr_id` is only counted as one throughout the entire array, ie. make a cumulative sum of unique `usr_id`' sorted by day.

If you have ideas of better optimising the MySQL query, that is welcome too.

**EDIT**: I would like the "cumulation" to happen over the entire array, not just per day, as in my example output, ie. day 1 is 1, day 2 is 3 (1+2), day 3 is 5 (3+2)... etc.

Comment: Do you always want the ID counted on the earliest date (or a specific date) and are you trying to avoid passing over the data twice?

Comment: @DaveCoast what matters is that it's sorted by date ascending, and I would like id's that have already been used on a any date to be omitted.

Comment: It will be interesting to see an elegant solution. I would have to do it in 2 steps, An Query grouping ID and min date, then count the ID's with a running total in PHP.

Comment: @DaveCoast the date is already sorted, I guess the challenge is, at least to me, to efficiently taking out duplicates of id's not only within a specific date, but the entire result stack...

Comment: Yea, but using `MIN(date)` you only get an ID once on it's earliest date, isn't that what is desired?

Comment: @DaveCoast I see what you mean now. From this perspective, it does count what date it happened. To make it simple: I would like the count of id's a day to cumulate into the total number of id's (interacted) at the end, each day adding the number of id's for that given date minus the duplicates of the entire result... makes sense...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first group unique users by day like this:

```
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $days[$item['date_stamp']][$item['usr_id']] = 1; // value is irrelevant
}
```

Then you can create an array of all the users, union each day's users onto it and count the result of that to get the cumulative sum.

```
$all_users = array();
foreach ($days as $day => $users) {
    $all_users = $all_users + $users;
    $result[] = array('sum' => count($all_users), 'date_stamp' => $day);
}
```

Comment: I edited the question in the meantime, and added an extra row to the original array to better demonstrate what I want: the extra row has the same id (2) as the duplicate one of `2011/6/20`, your script will take care of only one duplication, the one within `2011/6/20` but will ignore the one in the new date, so it will add that to the count too instead of omitting it... updated your eval: https://3v4l.org/pKcJj - the end result should be 5, not 6... hope this makes sense... :(

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about how array_merge treats numeric keys. I changed to to array union (+) and it seems to work properly now. https://3v4l.org/TvOGJ

Comment: Thank you! It was a fun problem.

Comment: Really happy you liked it! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would do that in SQL.

Something along those lines - this is Pseudo Code, not real SQL of course because I am MSSQL developer, but idea makes sense.

This will first select all the unique user IDs and their dates. Then it will group them by dates. After this, just run through it in PHP and add up.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(usr_id)
    date_stamp
    ts
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            DISTINCT usr_id,
            timestamp as ts,
            CONCAT(YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)), "/", MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)), "/", DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp))) as date_stamp
        FROM 
            table
    )
GROUP BY 
    date_stamp
ORDER BY 
    ts
```

Comment: This is only providing a count within the given date, doesn't do the cumulation, but I guess I could just do it in PHP, so this is actually a good suggestion, thank you.

Comment: Isn't the COUNT of unique ID's per days is what you are after? This should do it.

Comment: Yes, but I also would like it to cumulate over the entire array, sorry if that wasn't clear from the question, let me edit it...

Comment: Not Sure what you mean by cumulation...

What you will get from this query is something like: 

`array (size=3)
  '2011/6/6' => 1
  '2011/6/20' => 3
  '2011/6/21' => 2`

Comment: Yes, I tested it and it looks very close to what I'd like to achieve. By cumulation I mean `2011/6/6` should have 1, but `2011/6/20` should have 3 (not because there are 3 id's, but because 1, the previous value + 2, the value of the next day is 3 in total), then for `2011/6/21`, following the same logic, it would be 5, as in 3+2... There is one thing I'm not sure about your solution is whether it will show only the distinct id's within a day or will it be unique throughout the entire array (ie. no id should be repeated at all)...

Comment: That changes things quite a bit :) Now it's clear. Please update your question and I will update the answer ;)

Comment: I already edited my question with that a couple of minutes ago (see **EDIT** section at the bottom), hope it makes sense...

Comment: Updated the answer as well.

Comment: I'm either doing something wrong, or the sort / group in your query works alphabetically, not as numbers: eg. 29 is followed by 3, and only then by 30...

Comment: I am not doing sorting, only grouping. So add your own sorting as required.

Comment: well, the query I used took care of that too, it would make it a little more complicated to do another sort in PHP... I tried adding `ORDER BY date_stamp` to the end of your query, but that didn't make things better, any ideas?

Comment: Date stamp is a string, so you might want to select in the sub-query the year, month and day as well, and use those in your outer query to sort as you did in yours.

Comment: Very true! However I now added `ORDER BY YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(ir.create_time)), MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(ir.create_time)), DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(ir.create_time))` to the subquery (after `FROM table`), still the same issue, beats me why... are you sure it's not because we're grouping using the `date_stamp` string?

Comment: No, you want to SELECT those values from subquery, but use them in the top level query. ORDER  BY in subquery will result in wrong order :)

Comment: Sorry, man, could you maybe update the answer with that, please?

Comment: Edited, but you have to adjust it as MySQL requires. This is pseudo code.

Comment: This now produces totally different number (huge ones), but I guess it must be the way I implement your code, as I'm also doing joins and such, so it might be the reason this is messed up. Anyways, thanks for taking the time, I gave you an upvote, but I cannot accept it as the correct answer, especially as you only answered the SQL bit... ;)

Comment: No worries, hope it helps you at least somewhat ;)